# ASP.Net MVC - Unable to cast the LINQ query result into ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to bind a tree view menu control in a partialview with the ViewModel.
I have created a nested viewModel assuming that is the rightway to carry all the nested data needed for the navigation tree menu at one time and so I have wrote my linq query to fetch the data in a nested fashion. As newbie I am not 100% sure that this is the right way to do it. 
I am trying to bind my view model with Linq query result. My Model is nested and so is my Linq query. I am facing difficulty molding this two together. What ever way I try I am getting type casting error such as cannot convert from Type IQueriable to IList of collections.. My code:

```
        // ViewModel
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public decimal CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public decimal Badge { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCategories> CategorySubCategories { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubCategories
    {
        public decimal SubCategoryID { get; set; }
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
        public decimal Badge { get; set; }
        public List<Items> SubCategoryItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class Items
    {
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public List<SubItems> SubItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubItems
    {
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string SubItemName { get; set; }
    } 
}


//Databinding code:

    MyViewModel result = new MyViewModel();
            var query= (List<MyViewModel>)(from c in dbContext.TableName
                         where c.CHILD_ID == 0
                         select new MyViewModel
                         {
                             CategoryID = c.ELEMENT_ID,
                             CategoryName = c.CHILD_DESC,
                             CategorySubCategories = (List<SubCategories>)(from s in dbContext.TableName
                                                                           where s.PARENT_ID == c.ELEMENT_ID
                                                                           select new SubCategories
                                                                           {
                                                                               SubCategoryID = s.ELEMENT_ID,
                                                                               SubCategoryName = s.CHILD_DESC,
                                                                               SubCategoryItems = (List<Items>)(from i in dbContext.TableName
                                                                                                                where i.PARENT_ID == s.ELEMENT_ID
                                                                                                                select new Items
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    ID = i.ELEMENT_ID,
                                                                                                                    ItemName = i.CHILD_DESC
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                   )
                                                                           }
                                                                           )
                         });

return query.toList();
```

The error I am getting is @ line:  var query  = (List)(from c in dbContext.TableName
Error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyViewModel]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyViewModel]'.

Comment: Try adding a ToList() at the end of your select statement.

Comment: @Andrei, I did that and getting the same error:Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: I tried this 

var query = removed the castings in the top level and all sub levels added .ToList() in all levels and got the following error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SubCategories] ToList[SubCategories](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SubCategories])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your view model, change your List types to IEnumerable types.  Make sure not to use the .ToList() extension method on those sub selects.

The resulting types of your sub select statements are not instances of List, but do implement the IEnumerable interface.  They may implement ICollection, IList, etc, but you can play around with that.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the List<> to IEnumerable<> in my viewmodel. My implementation looks like this:MyViewModel result = new MyViewModel();
            result = (from c in dbContext.TableName
                      where c.CHILD_ID == 0
                      select new ToolNavigationViewModel
                      {
                          CategoryID = c.ELEMENT_ID,
                          CategoryName = c.CHILD_DESC,
                          CategorySubCategories = (IEnumerable<SubCategories>)(from s in dbContext.TableName ..................... But still getting the cast error

Comment: Is these the steps that you are suggesting:
1. changed the List<> to IEnumerable<> in viewmodel classes
2. Cast the main query and sub queries with thier appropriate ViewModel Ienumerables such as:
result = (IEnumerable<MyViewModel>)(from c in dbContext.TableName
..//sub queries
 (IEnumerable<SubCategories>)(from s in dbContext.TableName...
); but this is not helping.. I am missing something basic here..

Comment: Do you think flatenning the nested VM and model would help?

Comment: If it's set up right, you should not have to do any explicit casting at all with the LINQ query.  Remove ALL explicit casts in your LINQ query.  The changes I was suggesting was to the view model only.  Make your List<T> members IEnumberable<T> members.

Comment: Great ! Thanks. I went ahead and changed all the List in the VMs as IEnumerable removed the ToList() in the sub queries, removed all the casting. It worked. Thanks a bunch

Comment: could point to an article or any learning source where I can clarify the concepts involved in binding Linq queries with collection classes/VMs and related data structure features and compatibility. Thanks in advance

Comment: just curious to know.. I tried the same solution earlier but only difference was that I was using List instead of IEnumerable in my ViewModels and got into lot of issues. How did the IEnumerable solved all the issue

Comment: It's not that complicated, but it is very wordy, so I'll try to get it all to fit here. First, take note that the return type of the SELECT method is an IQueryable{T}, which inherits IEnumerable{T}.  When using LINQ-to-Entities (or LINQ-to-SQL), SELECT returns an unknown instance. You cannot assume that you'll know what it is, but you can assume that it is NOT an instance of the List{T} class, which is why your casting and original code failed). The instance returned by SELECT is implicitly an IEnumerable{T} which is why it works great with your modified view model. Hope that helps.

Comment: And to answer your previous question, it's not so much the LINQ part that you are having trouble with.  It's more basic than that.  There are lots of sources on these topics. Specifically, you want to get a handle on the difference between classes and interfaces, upcasting and downcasting, implicit/explicit casting, and inheritance.  You could wipe away every LINQ in your example, and you'd still have trouble if you tried to downcast an interface instance to a class that your instance didn't support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I think that I should strengthen my understanding of C# data structure

Comment: I am considering to learn this coarse at PluralSight -C# Collections Fundamentals: http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/csharp-collections If you get a chance please your suggestion. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know if this one will help.  This covers collections, but not basic C# fundamentals, which is what I believe would help.